# changing component properties of SkinnableComponent in Actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

Flex 4 separates the visual components into the skins.  So how do we access those visual elements from Skinnable component?  Here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SkinnableComponent xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"  skinClass="skins.brushedSkin"
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">


<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
import mx.controls.TextInput;

private var txt:String;

public function setText(s:String) {
txt = s;
// the following line doesn't work
var input:TextInput = this.skin.getChildByName("msg") as TextInput;
input.text = s;
}

]]>
</fx:Script>


</s:SkinnableComponent>
```

I just need to set the text in the TextInput in the brushedSkin skin.  But I have no idea how to do this in Flex 4.

Comment: SkinnableComponent is a base class and doesn't have its own skin.  The classes that derive off of SkinnableComponent will have their own skins, such as TextInput.  In the case above you need to create your own custom skin for your custom component and assign it either via CSS or at runtime.  I'm not sure what you are trying to do here, maybe you could provide some more context?  It almost looks like you are trying to create a custom component that has a TextInput, am I close?

Answer (score 3):

First you must specify in your SkinnableComponent the so called Designer-Developer Contract.
Then you should wait for your component to finish its instantiation in order to access its skin parts.

In your particular case you change your code in the following way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SkinnableComponent xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
     xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"  skinClass="skins.brushedSkin"
     xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">


<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
import mx.controls.TextInput;

[SkinPart(required="true")]
public var input:TextInput;

private var txt:String;

public function setText(s:String) {
    txt = s;
    if (initialized)
        input.text = txt;
} 
]]>
</fx:Script>

</s:SkinnableComponent>
```

Then ensure that your skin class contains the following declaration (probably you just need to rename the **msg**-TextInput to input):

`<s:TextInput id="input"/>`

Comment: This is in the right direction, but it would be better practice to use getter/setter to modify the property and also illustrate how to override the `partAdded` function.  That way you could get rid of the unnecessary clause "you should wait for your component to finish its instantiation in order to access its skin parts".

Comment: Well, initially I thought that giving a complete solution with the whole Flex component life-cycle would be needed (with the setter, invalidate properties, commitProperties, etc - overriding partAdded won't be needed in such sample). But then I realized that the question is not on how you set the properties in the Flex way, but on how you access that specific TextInput in the skin.